# cairosvg installed but ImportError

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, cairo

I just installed cairosvg and it seems to have worked.
If i try to install again it says:

> $ pip install cairosvg
>   Requirement already satisfied(...)

But if I try to import it in python3, it delivers an ImportError:

> >>>import cairosvg
>   Traceback(most recent call last):
>   (...)
>   ImportError: No Module named 'cairosvg'

Any ideas whats going wrong here? By the way, im trying to convert .svg files to .png ones, if there is a simpler possibility, feel free to tell me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

install with pip3:

```
pip3 install cairosvg
```

Comment: @hamedbaziyad whats your os? python version?

Comment: Windows 10 & Python 3.6

Comment: @hamedbaziyad you should use `pip` command instead of `pip3`. if it doesn't work please check you have one python interpreter.

Comment: Indeed, I have both Python 2.7 and Python 3.6

Comment: @hamedbaziyad just call pip from python3 path: for example if you installed python executable in `C:\python36` call pythob 3.6 pip in this way: `C:\python36\scripts\pip.exe install cairosvg`